# Django template tag a model object.

Tags: django

I'm trying to return a different value for my model object rather than the information stored in the field.
I'm running this in my html file. I've passed a query of 'localcampaigns' to my html file.

In my HTML file I have:

```
{% for campaign in localcampaigns %}
<a href="/campaigns/{{campaign.id}}/">{{campaign.title}}</a>
{{campaign.time}}
{{campaign.event_date}}
{{campaign.project_focus}}
{% endfor %}
```

So specifically, say I run this and for the {{campaign.project_focus}} I receive the database object of 'community001' - I want to take this and return something different than this 'community001' like "Community Project"

I've tried to do this by:

```
    {% if '{{campaign.project_focus}}' == 'community001' %}
    Community Project
    {% endif %}
```

But I'm unsuccessful. whenever I run != in the template tag, I get the response. So I know that the two don't match. How do I make the two match? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{% if campaign.project_focus == 'community001' %}
Community Project
{% endif %}
```

campaign.project_focus without {{ }} because it's recognized inside the for loop

Comment: Makes sense, Thank you.